# Leaflet.js popup and zoom

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to make a leaflet.js popup show up at specific zoom levels please, for example when `map.getZoom() > 6` only. Hiding the popup or even setting its opacity to zero could also be viable options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the method/event handler `map.on('zoomend')` (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-zoomend) to detect whenever the map finishes zooming. Then check the zoom value do see if you want to show the popup or not.

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
  if(map.getZoom() > 6){
    showPopup();//your function here
  } 
});
```

Comment: I think i got it. This is how my code now roughly looks like. I dont have something like `marker.bindPopup` something that got me stuck.
 
    `L.geoJson(data, {pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {//some code goes 
        here})},
                onEachFeature: onEachMarker
            })


    function onEachMarker(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({popupopen: onPopupOpen,});
        layer.bindPopup(myPopup, customOptions)
    }


    function onPopupOpen(e) {
        if ( map.getMaxZoom() < 6 ) {
           this.closePopup();
      }
    }`